# How can I run an unsaved file?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way in notepad++ to use the "Run > Launch in ..." functions on unsaved files? If you do this, it just tries to open "{notepad++-Dir}\new 1", which doesn't exist of course.

I sometimes just want to see the output of some small scribbles without having to manually save them in a temp dir or something.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This will quite simply not be possible. When you create a new document in NPP, this will only exist in your RAM and nowhere  on the disk until it has been made persistent by saving. Other programs will not be able to run this since they need to load it from the disk.

Comment: I once had an editor (dont't remember its name) that would save the file into the temporary folder for this purpose. That would solve this problem, but is there a way to in npp to do that?

Answer (score -1):

It's not like I'm an expert at scripting or anything, but if it's minor edits, why don't you just save the changes, run it, and then hit ctrl+z?

Comment: It's not about small changes on an existing file. I write something or copy from another program, and just want to run that content. So it's not saved anywhere... And saving a temporary file just to delete it immediately is a bit cumbersome